# Problem assigning to findItemByCategoryRequest.outputSelector[] using eBay API .NET SDK

Tags: .net, ebay-api, ebay-net-sdk

I'm trying to assign a value with code like the following:

```
findItemByCategoryRequest r = new findItemByCategoryRequest()
r.outputSelector = outputSelectorType.SellerInfo

........etc
```

However I am getting an error when I try to build:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'FinalEbayParser.com.ebay.developer.OutputSelectorType'
to 'FinalEbayParser.com.ebay.developer.OutputSelectorType[]'"
```

Now I would expect there to be an Object, some sort of array of outputSelectorTypes..but one doesn't seem to exist in the Ebay Finding API for .NET

There is such a thing for itemFilters (itemFilter[]) which you can assign a various number of item filters and then assign the itemFilter[] object to the property r.itemFilter

Any help is much appreciated with this, it is all I need working to sign off on a project that is already over due. The Ebay website itself gives very very little info about using the API with .NET and I have a feeling this may even be something they have forgotten completely somehow...Apparently that's happened in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign a single object to a property that is an *array* of such objects. Now, I haven't used the eBay API, so I don't know exactly how it works, but you could try to assign an array instead:

```
r.outputSelector = new[] { outputSelectorType.SellerInfo };
```

If you are using a C# version that does not support type inference you will need to explicitly state the array type:

```
r.outputSelector = new OutputSelectorType[] { outputSelectorType.SellerInfo };
```